# Replace Underscores with Slash AND remove ".php" in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've search the internet and Stackoverflow for hours now and I just can't fix my problem completely. I already figured it out years ago, but lost the file and I can't reconstruct it anymore. So I'm hoping for your help!

I've HTML-URLs and I want to simulate folders AND I also want to remove the extension `.html`

```
INPUT: domain.com/file.html
OUTPUT: domain.com/file/

INPUT: domain.com/folder1_folder2_file.html
OUTPUT: domain.com/folder1/folder2/file/
```

I'm also not so sure about the flags at the end of the line.

Notworking code so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)?_([^_]*)?_(.*)$ $1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you visit `domain.com/file/` in browser now, does it open `/file.html`?

Comment: No, it still shows the not found page.

Comment: in that case you will internal rewrite from `/folder1/folder2/file/` to `/folder1_folder2_file.html` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured it out myself. It rewrites URLs with non-digit characters and dashs.

For anyone interested:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z-]+)$ $1.html [N]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)$ $1_$2_$3.html [L]
```

Nevertheless, thank you for your efforts =) @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Hi Thank your for letting know your working solution, for my solution did you get any error etc? It was working fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} _
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html/?$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^.]*)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/%3/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !_
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html/?$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]*)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Testing with curl command:

```
curl -IL "http://localhost:80/file.html"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/file/

curl -IL "http://localhost:80/folder1_folder2_file.html"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/folder1/folder2/file/
```

Comment: I tried the first code snippet. Does not work. 404 Error.

I'm not sure what to do with the second.

Comment: @Mel, could you please do let me know if you are hitting link `http://localhost:80/folder1_folder2_file.html`(you could put your domain name), when I used it worked perfectly fine for me, let me know?